# find same record for multiple fields in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userinfo` (
  `user_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_code` varchar(20),
  `party1_id` varchar(200),
  `party2_id` varchar(200),
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `userinfo` (`user_id`, `user_code`, `party1_id`, `party2_id`) VALUES
  ('1', '05B29E57', '1', ''),
  ('2', '05B29E58', NULL, '1'),
  ('3', '05B29E59', '2', ''),
  ('4', '05B29E60', NULL, '2'),
  ('5', '05B29E61', '3',''),
  ('6', '05B29E62', NULL, '3'),
  ('7', '05B29E63', NULL, '4'),
  ('8', '05B29E64', NULL, '5'),
  ('9', '05B29E65', NULL, '6'),
  ('10', '05B29E66', NULL, '7');
```

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| user_id | user_code | party1_id | party2_id |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|       1 | 05B29E57  | 1         |           |
|       2 | 05B29E58  | NULL      |         1 |
|       3 | 05B29E59  | 2         |           |
|       4 | 05B29E60  | NULL      |         2 |
|       5 | 05B29E61  | 3         |           |
|       6 | 05B29E62  | NULL      |         3 |
|       7 | 05B29E63  | NULL      |         4 |
|       8 | 05B29E64  | NULL      |         5 |
|       9 | 05B29E65  | NULL      |         6 |
|      10 | 05B29E66  | NULL      |         7 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

So i have above table as `userinfo`. Due to some reason i have to find the duplicate records for party1_id & party2_id.

I have tried below:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM userinfo u1
  JOIN userinfo u2
    ON u1.party1_id = u2.party2_id
WHERE IFNULL(u1.party1_id, 0) > 0
AND IFNULL(u1.party2_id, '') = ''
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/725eff/1

But it didn't give result in a way i want, it just returns 3 record. Is there a way to archive my expected output with sorting same as in my expected output.

Expected Output:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| user_id | user_code | party1_id | party2_id |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|       1 | 05B29E57  | 1         |           |
|       2 | 05B29E58  | NULL      |         1 |
|       3 | 05B29E59  | 2         |           |
|       4 | 05B29E60  | NULL      |         2 |
|       5 | 05B29E61  | 3         |           |
|       6 | 05B29E62  | NULL      |         3 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: In your expected   output you have 6 records ..  explian better  ..

Comment: yes that is my expected output but the query which i execute only return 3 record.

Comment: @scaisEdge i am trying to achieve result similar to my expected output (i.e. 6 record) but my actual output has only 3 record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try following.

```
select * from userinfo where 
party1_id  in (
  SELECT
  u1.party1_id
FROM userinfo u1
  JOIN userinfo u2
    ON u1.party1_id = u2.party2_id
WHERE IsNULL(u1.party1_id, 0) > 0
AND IsNULL(u1.party2_id, '') = '') or party2_id in ( SELECT
  u1.party1_id
FROM userinfo u1
  JOIN userinfo u2
    ON u1.party1_id = u2.party2_id
WHERE IsNULL(u1.party1_id, 0) > 0
AND IsNULL(u1.party2_id, '') = '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could obtain the expected  result using union

```
select t1.* 
from userinfo t1
inner join  (
    select a.party1_id apid, b.party2_id bpid
     FROM userinfo a
      JOIN userinfo b
        ON a.party1_id = b.party2_id
) t2 on t2.apid = t1.party1_id
UNION 
select t1.* 
from userinfo t1
inner join  (
    select a.party1_id apid, b.party2_id bpid
     FROM userinfo a
      JOIN userinfo b
        ON a.party1_id = b.party2_id
) t2 on t2.apid = t1.party2_id
order by user_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/725eff/17

for performance   be sure you have al least thiese  indexes

```
idx1  table userinfo columns (party1_id, party2_id)

idx2 table userinfo columns (party2_id, party1_id)
```

Comment: @DS9 I ran a similar query in a shared hosting mysql table with half a million records and on varchar non-indexed columns, it took just 3 seconds. The point is, query in this answer or my answer should not take this long. Try to look at the database, server settings etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM userinfo u1
  where
  u1.party1_id in (select distinct u2.party2_id from userinfo u2) 
  or 
  u1.party2_id in (select distinct u3.party1_id from userinfo u3)
```

Below is the output I get in your fiddle for above query:(order by can be applied to any column)

```
user_id     user_code   party1_id   party2_id
1           05B29E57    1   
2           05B29E58    (null)      1
3           05B29E59    2   
4           05B29E60    (null)      2
5           05B29E61    3   
6           05B29E62    (null)      3
```